# How would I find the height of each node and assign it postorder in a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have a templated class with an additional  Node class with a height attribute. I want to be able to validate the height of each node after a new node has been inserted. My insert node function is working well, I am just confused on how I would change the height of each node after a new node is inserted.

````
template <typename T>
class BST
{
public:
    class Node 
    {
    public:
        T key;
        int height = 0;    
        Node* left = nullptr;
        Node* right = nullptr;
        Node* parent = nullptr;
       
        Node(){}
       
        Node(T k, Node* input_node = nullptr)
        {
            key = k;
            parent = input_node;
        }
    };

private:
   
    Node* root_ = nullptr;
    unsigned int size_ = 0;

public:

   BST(); 

   ~BST();

   void insert(T k);

private: 

    void fix_height(Node* node);


template <typename T>
void BST<T>::insert(T k)
{
    
    Node* node = root_; // insert function 
    Node* prev_node = node;
    bool went_right;

    if(node == nullptr)
    {
        root_ = new Node(k);
        ++size_;
        return;
    }
    while(node != nullptr)
    {
        prev_node = node;
        if(k < node->key)
        {
            node = node->left;
            went_right = false;
        }
        else if (k > node->key)
        {
            node = node->right;
            went_right = true;
        }
        
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if(went_right)
    {
        prev_node->right= new Node(k, prev_node); // assigning the new node 
    }
    else
    {
        prev_node->left= new Node(k, prev_node);
    }
    ++size_;

    
    
}

template <typename T> 
void BST<T>::fix_height(Node* node)
{


}```
````

Comment: When you return from a recursive insertion call, you simply update the current node's height as the maximum of its child nodes' heights plus 1.

Comment: Oh, I took a look at your code and see that it is not recursive. So in this case, you should walk back through the tree by following your parent pointers, and update the height at each node visited, all the way back to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of a node is defined as the maximum of its child nodes' heights plus 1.

Although your question title speaks of "post-order" (a term related to recursion), your code is not actually recursive. Normally, a post-order update happens after a recursive call.

Anyway, with your iterative solution the height can still be updated easily because you have stored parent pointers in your tree nodes. And so all you need to do is walk back through each node and update the height.

```
template <typename T> 
void BST<T>::fix_height(Node* node)
{
    while (node)
    {
        node->height = 1 + std::max(
            node->left ? node->left->height : -1,
            node->right ? node->right->height : -1);
        node = node->parent;
    }
}
```

It should be noted that your tree heights appear to treat a leaf node's height (that is, the height of a node that has no children) as 0. In order to make your `fix_height` function well-behaved even if called on a leaf node, then the height of "no child" is treated as -1.

If you decide that a leaf node's height should actually be 1, then you should change those "no child" heights to 0, and change the default height of a new node to 1.

To use this, you would call `fix_height(prev_node);` just before returning from your `insert` function.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question I appreciate it. I am just trying to understand what you have written here. Is this solution not a recursive solution? I have understood that the height of a node is defined as the maximum of its child nodes' heights plus 1. So it makes sense to me  that you are using std::max. Then you have returned -1 if the condition is not true so that will equal 0 meaning the node is a leaf node? I hope I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: No, your solution is _iterative_. Read up on the definition of recursion in programming if you wish to understand the difference. Regarding the calculation, yes you have understood it correctly.

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble understanding  `while (node)` should there not be a condition for the loop? Also why do we need `node = node->parent`

Comment: `node` is the condition. If you prefer `node != nullptr` that's fine. It's the same thing. You need `node = node->parent` because you need to walk back through the tree hierarchy of the node whose height is being updated. That's because if the node's height changes, its parent heights might also change. This is the iterative step of your loop. The loop will keep going until you end up following the root's parent, which is `nullptr` and so the loop terminates.

Comment: Wow that makes much more sense to me now. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @paddy, Sorry to bother you again. I am now working on inorder successor function. My parameters are only the key of the function. I was just wondering would I have to write a search helper function to find the successor?

Comment: This is the point where you open a new question, explaining what "inorder successor function" is, showing your code and describe the issue you're having. That way, it's visible to the whole community, not hidden away in the comments on an accepted answer to an unrelated question.